# Win32 exception then using Httpclient inside Application constructor

Tags: c#, maui

I am trying to load some files in my .NET MAUI application, I am using HttpClient inside my `Application` constructor (I know that I should be using App lifecycle events) :

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TestAsync();
    }

    private async Task TestAsync()
    {
        HttpClient lClient = new HttpClient();
        var lReponse = await lClient.GetAsync(new Uri("https://proof.ovh.net/files/1Mb.dat"));
        using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\test.dat", FileMode.CreateNew))
        {
            await lReponse.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
        }
    }
}
```

I always end up with the following error on Windows (An unhandled win32 exception occurred) on the `var lReponse = await lClient.GetAsync` part :

[image]

In a .NET 6 WPF project this is working fine :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TestAsync();
    }

    private async Task TestAsync()
    {
        HttpClient lClient = new HttpClient();
        var lReponse = await lClient.GetAsync(new Uri("https://proof.ovh.net/files/1Mb.dat"));
        using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\test.dat", FileMode.CreateNew))
        {
            await lReponse.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something specific in the lifecycle of the `Application` class that impact async/await (something related to the SynchronizationContext ?) ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: likely your user does not have permission to write to the root of the `C:\ ` drive

Comment: add a try/catch and get the exception object and see what it tells you

Comment: @daniel-a-white I tried with other paths (`FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory`), same result. Seems unlikely to me that it is a filesystem problem since the error is on `lClient.GetAsync` and it work in WPF.

Comment: @Jason no luck with that (same error, same place, catch never reach) nothing in the output as well

Comment: Please post the complete exception details, including message and call stack. And code, if you can get it.

Comment: @stephen-cleary unhandled exception doesn't give much informations on its own (the screen  I gave is all you get), anyway I found a way to handle this kind of exceptions and solved my problem. Thanks you all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by the missing `MainPage` initalization. In .NET MAUI you have to set MainPage in the constructor of App, this will fix my code sample :

```
public App()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   TestAsync();

   MainPage = new AppShell();
}
```

I found out thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443528/how-to-catch-unhandled-win32-exception-occured-in-appname-procid) stackoverflow, how you can handle this type of unhandled exception like so :

```
public App()
{
    // Catch all handled exceptions in managed code, before the runtime searches the Call Stack 
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += FirstChanceException;
    InitializeComponent();
    TestAsync();
}

private void FirstChanceException(object sender, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

Which gave me the following exception :

`System.NotImplementedException: 'Either set MainPage or override CreateWindow.'`

In my original code I was setting the main page after the await of my async call, which is after the constructor finished it's execution hence the error (no idea it was hide by a win32 unhandled exception though).